# Split array of +ve and -ve nums

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve this interview problem. I was able to get an O(N) solution with O(N) space complextity. I am trying to figure out if there is a solution with **O(1) space**?

**Question:**

Given an unsorted array of positive and negative numbers. Create an array of alternate positive and negative numbers **without** changing the relative order of positive and negative numbers respectively.

**Input:**

The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases.
The first line of each test case is N,N is the size of array.
The second line of each test case contains N input a[].

**Output:**

Print an array of alternate positive and negative numbers.
Note: Solution should start with positive number.

**Constraints:**

1 ≤ T ≤ 30
1 ≤ N ≤ 100
-1000 ≤ a[] ≤ 1000

**Example:**

Input

```
1
9
9 4 -2 -1 5 0 -5 -3 2
```

Output

```
9 -2 4 -1 5 -5 0 -3 2
```

.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //code
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = sn.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<T; i++){
            int N = sn.nextInt();
            ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayList<Integer> pv_arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayList<Integer> ne_arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
                int num = sn.nextInt();
                if(num<0){
                    ne_arr.add(num);
                }else{
                    pv_arr.add(num);
                }
            }

            int maxLen = Math.max(pv_arr.size(), ne_arr.size());
            for(int k = 0; k < maxLen; k++){
              if(k < pv_arr.size()){
                 System.out.print(pv_arr.get(k) + " ");
              }
              if(k < ne_arr.size()){
                 System.out.print(ne_arr.get(k) + " ");
              }
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

My answer creates two arrays positive & negative and prints them alternatively. I tried using two pointers (one of positive values and one of negative values) I am not sure how to solve this with O(N) & O(1) space.

Comment: Is it guaranteed there is a solution? I.e. there is the same numbers of negative and positive integers (or at most different by 1).

Comment: I am not sure if there is a solution for O(N) time and O(1) space complexity. I was just trying to figure out the optimal way to solve this problem.

Comment: I mean the solution to the problem. I.e. Input 1 5 1 1 1 1 1 seems invalid.

Comment: Are the numbers given to you as Strings that you have to read using a scanner? The question suggests that this is the case.

Comment: @luk32 Valid point. I think if all the numbers are positive then you just exit or print the array without modifications.

Comment: @keiwan I didn't put too much thought into reading the input. How would you read the inputs if they are not Strings?

Comment: @YeshwanthVenkatesh I explained what I mean by that in my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **do not** directly get an array as the input to your function but instead have to read the numbers from the standard input stream it means that you'll have to **create the array** yourself. Also the question states:

> The first line...
>   The second line...

implying that the input is given to you line by line and not as parameters to a function.

This would mean that the best solution is O(n) in terms of space. You have already found a solution that works but you could still simplify it using a "pointer" approach like you had said yourself:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = sn.nextInt();
    for(int i=0; i<T; i++){
        int N = sn.nextInt();
        int[] numbers = new int[N];
        int neg_ind = 1;
        int pos_ind = 0;

        for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
            int num = sn.nextInt();
            if(num < 0){
                numbers[neg_ind] = num;
                neg_ind += 2;
            }else{
                numbers[pos_ind] = num;
                pos_ind += 2;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }
}
```

Comment: But is this really `O(n)` space complexity. Because the question **requires** you to create an array. And so this cannot be considered as extra space. If you were to read it into an array as it were and then create a new array and then apply the logic in your code then it would be `O(n)` space.

Comment: @thebenman I see what you mean but I'd say it's essentially an `O(n)` solution because the question requires it to be a `O(n)` solution. Since the input is not given as an array but as a stream of numbers that you have to turn into an array it's additional space and therefore adds to the space complexity.